Do you say "in the dotted line"?
"dotted line" often goes with "on".
For example, these are from Oxford dictionary
Write your name on the dotted line.
Just sign on the dotted line and the car is yours.
Also, British says "fill in" and American says "fill out". I am not sure these are all correct:
British English

Please fill in the form

Please fill in the coupon

Please fill in the blanks

Please fill in the dotted line (not sure if it is correct)


American English

Please fill out the form

Please fill out the coupon

Please fill out the blanks (not sure if it is correct)

Please fill out the dotted line (not sure if it is correct)


A "dotted line" often goes with "on", so "fill in the dotted line" might sound strange.
Note:
Several examples from Google Book say "fill in the dotted line", no one says "fill on the dotted line".
Ngram also confirms that.
Look at this text

If I can not say "fill in the dotted lines", what are other ways to say?
For example, can I say "write your answers on the dotted lines"?
Note: I listed all other examples to let people think about them at a holistic level. American says "fill out the blanks" and why "out" here? which does not make any sense, so I guess the noun after "fill in" and "fill out" is not important.

Fill in the blanks, and sign on the dotted line.

It's not clear what you actually want to know. Do you want to know the usual way of telling people to write an answer on a dotted line? Do you want a list of every possible way you might instruct someone to write something on a form? Is there one specific sentence/phrase you want to know about, because you can't just ask ten different questions? You also ask about a bunch of other unconnected phrases like "Please fill out the coupon" which are syntactically completely distinct. And then when someone answers you argue with them.

@StuartF, I listed all other examples to let people think about them at a holistic level. American says "fill out the blanks" and why "out" here? which does not make any sense, so I guess the noun after "fill in" and "fill out" is not important. Or something like that.

I’m voting to close this question because it's not clear what you actually want to know.

Americans do not say "fill out the blanks" we say "fill out the form" and  "fill in the blanks".

See this usage chart for all 4 permutations of fill in / out the cheque / check. We can rely on spelling more confidently than Google Books corpus selection, so that chart proves pretty conclusively that your idea about a US/UK usage split between fill in and fill out (a form) is effectively spurious. You certainly shouldn't have wasted brain cells committing it to memory.

From a British (and I assume universal) point of view "fill in the dotted line" is definitely wrong. This is a point of fact rather than grammar. If you write in a box on a form you are writing in it. You are never writing "in" the dotted line, only ever "on" (i.e. above) it. In fact the only way anything can ever be in a line if it's part of the line.

several examples from Google Book say "fill in the dotted line" no one says "fill on the dotted line".

Ngram also confirms that . https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fill+in+the+dotted+line%2C+fill+on+the+dotted+line&year_start=1800&year_end=2022&corpus=en&smoothing=3

Those few books that use the phrase presumably mean 'fill in the gap in the sentence indicated by a dotted line' (one seems to refer to colouring in a shape outlined by dotted lines). The fact that there are so few indicates that it's not very idiomatic.

@Tom do you want to know what's most common, in which case this answer is correct? Or do you want to know every possible way it's ever been expressed? You need to be clearer about what you actually want to know.

@KateBunting, look at the image I have just updated. They said "fill in the dotted line". If we don't say "fill in the dotted line", what should we say ? "fill in the blanks"? but a "dotted line"  is not a blank?

Context matters. I would interpret your boxed example as fill in [the space marked by] the dotted line. Here to fill in means "to complete". But generally the advice given you is definitely right. We write on a line, not in a line. Note also that you are mixing different verbs. So of course the related prepositions may vary.

As I said, they mean "fill in the blank indicated by the dotted line".

I think that this sort of "well, just think about it. you're clearly ON the dotted line, not IN it" approach to prepositions is sometimes less-than-helpful for English learners. You can usually make the opposite argument sound equally convincing. E.g. (WRONG!!!) "You should prefer "write your name in the dotted line", because you're writing it between the boundaries of the left side of the line and the right side of the line, the same way you're in a field even if you're not contained inside the dirt. Writing your name ON the line would mean putting it directly overlapping with the line"

Or I guess my point is, the reason we native speakers think "the writing is on the line" is because on is the preposition used for writing something on a line, but if it were in, we would be saying exactly the same thing with in instead. We can point to general patterns but i think we do a disservice to everybody to pretend that in/on is something you can deduce via pure logic. For instance, the blank in Fill in the blank: ____________ is absolutely something you write on but in that case, in is correct

You can be "in" a space, e.g. a blank in this context, but a line (again, in this context) is clearly conceptually one dimensional so you cannot be "in" it. If I saw "fill in the dotted line" as an instruction I would be looking for a box bounded by a dotted line.
